# How to access a private Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to plug in a snippet of someone else's code into a much larger script of my own. I need to extract the comment ID for each comment.

This is the code for output:

```
<?php
$comments = array();
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_id` = '$pageID' ORDER BY `id` ASC");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $comments[] = new Comment($row2);
}
print_r($comments);

$i = 0;
foreach($comments as $c) {
echo $c->markup();
echo $i."<br>";
$currCommID = $c->id;
echo "<br/>current id is: ".$currCommID;
  $i++;
}
```

As expected, getting an error: Notice: Undefined property: Comment::$id

This is the data I get with print_r($comments); - I can see the IDs I want but I can't get to them.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Comment Object
        (
            [data:Comment:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [id] => 2
                    [1] => gocat
                    [name] => gocat
                    [2] => 857
                    [page_id] => 857
                    [3] => this is some other comment
                    [body_txt] => this is some other comment
                    [4] => 2015-10-29 09:35:53
                    [dt] => 2015-10-29 09:35:53
                    [5] => 0
                    [up] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                    [down] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Comment Object
        (
            [data:Comment:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [id] => 8
                    [1] => lolcat
                    [name] => lolcat
                    [2] => 857
                    [page_id] => 857
                    [3] => funny comment
                    [body_txt] => funny comment
                    [4] => 2015-10-29 09:35:53
                    [dt] => 2015-10-29 09:35:53
                    [5] => 0
                    [up] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                    [down] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

The values I want are 2 and 8 in this case.

Yes I could just make my own query. The reason I want to keep it is the markup(); function. It outputs the comments pre-formated exactly how I want them.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the structure of this array, hopefully you can shed some light on it.
thanks.

*UPDATE: Sorry, can't post an answer because I was marked as duplicate. TBH, I didn't find a solution in this other thread.*

So, I edited the comment class which looks like this:

```
<?php
private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        $this->data = $row;
    }
?>
```

Now I have:

```
<?php
private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        $this->data = $row;
    }

    public function commentids()
    {               
        $e = &$this->data;
        return $e['id'];
    }
?>
```

Then I changed the output code to this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($comments as $c) {
echo $c->markup();
$currCommID = $c->commentids();
echo "<br/>current id is: ".$currCommID;
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Its an array of objects of type `Comment`. Probably that class defines methods like `getId()` or similar, to expose its internal data. Have a look in the class definition

Comment: Yes, it's private and inaccessible. You will need to look at the `Comment` class and see if there are any functions which return the values you want. @Steve is pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Can somebody please unmark this as duplicate? I've posted a solution. "You cannot access it" is not an actionable solution. Even Steve's comment in this thread is much more helpful than the answers in the other thread.